# rails form update method not called

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I try to update my settings through a form but the update function is not called when I submit. It redirects to edit_settings_path when I submit and as per serve log update is not called. Why?

```
<%= form_tag settings_path, :method => :put do %>
<p>
  <%= label_tag :"settings[:default_email]", "System Administrator" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :"settings[:default_email]", Settings['default_email'] %>
</p>
  <span class="submit"><%= submit_tag "Save settings" %></span>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    params[:settings].each do |name, value|
     Settings[name] = value
    end

   redirect_to edit_settings_path, :notice => "Settings have been saved." }
  end
end
```

** Update **
Update is now called properly (edited controller). Server log confirms `Settings Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "settings".* FROM "settings" WHERE "settings"."thing_type" IS NULL AND "settings"."thing_id" IS NULL AND "settings"."var" = ':default_email' LIMIT 1
UPDATE "settings" SET "value" = '--- 1111aaa2222...', "updated_at" = '2011-12-18 21:03:21.782075' WHERE "settings"."id" = 2`

However it doesn't save to the Db and have no clue why. I'm using the Rails-settings gem 'git://github.com/100hz/rails-settings.git'
Don't know where to check since it says it updated record but in fact no.

Comment: Did you set up the route accordingly in the router?

Comment: Yep I have 'resource :settings'. Now it updates according to Server log 'Settings Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "settings".* FROM "settings" WHERE "settings"."thing_type" IS NULL AND "settings"."thing_id" IS NULL AND "settings"."var" = ':default_email' LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE "settings" SET "value" = '--- 1111aaa2222...', "updated_at" = '2011-12-18 21:03:21.782075' WHERE "settings"."id" = 2' but it doesn't save to Db

Comment: you have to call save yourself

Comment: where? In the console I get `{"default_email"=>"my@email.ca", "address"=>"2277 Riverside drive\n", ":default_email"=>"email3@myemail.ca", ":address"=>"211 Bank street"}` looks like it duplicates settings and not render the right one. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

why are you using the form_tag method?

If you are just trying to make a standard update form, use:

```
<%= form_for(@settings) do |f| %>
      FORM CODE
<%= end %>
```

Your controller uses the edit method to render the view and the update method for the calback (to interact with the model)

If you insist on using

```
<%= form_tag setting_path, :method => :put do %>
```

Normally you would use the singular word if you are working on a member and the plural if you are working on an collection.

fyi: I dont know what your design is like, but i would have a model settings and a model settings_item...

Comment: Form fixed at least it updates but does not save now. Using the rails-settings gem to store data in "vertical" way. Thanks for joining